# Question about convergence of infinite products

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$, is it true that $\prod_{n}(1+x_n)$ is bounded above by $e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n}$ and hence $\prod_{n}(1+x_n)$ converges or diverges depending on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_n\left(1+x_n\right)$$ exactly ?

Comment: $\prod_n (1+x_n) = (1+x_1)(1+x_2)..$ and by the limit I mean, is this product bounded above by $e^{\sum x_n}$

Comment: "bounded above" makes it a very different question !

Comment: True, my bad, don't know why I did that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $|x_n|<1$, $$\sum_{n=1}^m\log(1+x_n)=\sum_{n=1}^mx_n-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^mx_n^2+\frac13\sum_{n=1}^mx_n^3-\cdots$$

and there is no reason that

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\log(1+x_n)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^mx_n.$$

---

**Given the change of the question, this answer is irrelevant.**